# What do you call a poem or song that sets up a rhyme and then ignores it?

Tags: poetry, rhymes

Here is a line from the song "[Popular](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=popular%20wicked&oq=popular%20&gs_l=youtube.1.0.0l10.959.2177.0.3796.8.7.0.1.1.0.114.576.6j1.7.0...0.0...1ac.1.LjDB-_Qd8d0)" in the musical *Wicked*. I am trying to explain what we call the anticlimax of the last three lines, where a rhyme is expected but not delivered.

> When I see depressing creatures/
>   With unprepossessing features/
>   I remind them on their own behalf/
>   To think of/
>   Celebrated heads of state or/
>   Specially great communicators/
>   Did they have brains or knowledge?/
>   Don't make me laugh!He,he!/
>   They were popular!

Is there a term for the rhyme scheme where we (arguably) expect knowledge to be rhymed with "college"?

Another example:

> Roses are red/Violets are blue/Sugar is sweet/And so am I

The comedic effect of that poem is in the anticlimax of the final line. Is there a term for that anticlimax created from an unmade rhyme?

Comment: By the way, I think this is not *broken rhyme* (aka *split rhyme*).

Comment: Keep your feet off the grass
Shine your shoes, wipe your...face http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6qcBQoK7uI&t=0m12s

Comment: @Kris: Thanks. I'm not sure what to call it. I'll just stick with anticlimactic.

Comment: *"I am just a poor boy. / Though my story's seldom told, / I have squandered my resistance / For a pocketful of mumbles"* — Paul Simon

Comment: Best/ worst examples I can recall; I heard both in the late 1970s: "Rah rah rhee,
Kick 'em in the knee!
Rah rah rass,
Kick 'em in the other knee!" (Apologies in advance for anyone offended by the apparent underlying misogyny; citation does not imply agreement. Besides, a case could be made that the actual attitude is anti-patriarchal. At the time, unlike now, fewer women than men went to college in the US. "Subverted" rhyming indeed.): "When hens finish growing,
They're ready for plucking;
When girls finish high school,
They're ready for college."

Comment: for more examples see any episode of up pompeii

Comment: Roses are red / Violets are blue / Some poems rhyme / But this one doesn't.

Comment: @mplungjan I think the *Shrek* example is a little different. You're supposed to expect a specific word, not just the rhyme. The rhyme is a tool to misdirect the audience to precisely that word. Maybe it's a matter of degrees, but I see it as a different end product.

Comment: Right. So a climax that is not even close to what was expected.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a ***subverted rhyme***.

I hesitate to cite [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SubvertedRhymeEveryOccasion) directly but the term has also appeared [in ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/what-term-describes-enjambment-alluding-to-a-taboo-word).

Comment: HA! My example is the first in the link's Animated section - I should have searched with it _shine your shoes off the grass wipe your face shrek rhyme_  found your link

Comment: +1 for correct term, +1 for link to alternate discussion in ELU, -1 for ruining the rest of my day with a link to TVTropes. Net +1, but still.... grr.